# Unable to access php variables returned by class method using include_once and ob_start function

Tags: php

I have 2 classes one is **Language.php** and the second is **Landing.php**.

The language class contains :

```
<?php

namespace App\Core;

class Language {
           
    function getLanguage($language = null)
    {
        $lang = $this->setLanguage($language);
        if(file_exists(LANGUAGE_DIR ."/".$lang.".php"))
        {
            ob_start();
            include LANGUAGE_DIR."/".$lang.".php"; //INCLUDE EN.PHP
            return ob_get_clean();
            
        } else {
            
            ob_start();
            include LANGUAGE_DIR."/en.php";
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
    }
}
```

The landing class contains:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Landing;

use App\Core\Database;
use App\Core\Language;

class Landing extends Database 
{
    public function reportBug(string $language, int $video, string $sender, string $commentaire)
    {
        $lang = new Language;
        $lang->getLanguage($language);   //THIS DOESN'T WORK
        //include LANGUAGE_DIR."/".$language.".php";  //UNCOMMENT THIS LINE EVERYTHING WORKS

        //Save the comment 
        $rowCount = $this->insert("INSERT INTO comments(video, message)VALUES(?, ?)", array($video, $commentaire), false);     
        if($rowCount == 1){
            return '1'; //Success
        }else {
            return '<div class="alert alert-danger">'. $commentNotSent .'</div>'; //$commentNotSent throw error 
        }
    }

}
```

I have also this file **en.php**:

```
<?php

$commentNotSent = "Comment not sent";
```

The problem is that I cannot display **$commentNotSent** variable. Can you help me please?

Comment: `ob_start()` is not needed here because "en.php" does not write anything into the output buffer. When you include "en.php", the variable `$commentNotSent` is available locally, inside the function `getLanguage()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Syscall but how to get it in reportBug function?

Comment: change your en.php to something like `return ["commentNotSent" => "Comment not sent"];` and getLanguage to `$file = file_exists(LANGUAGE_DIR ."/".$lang.".php")) ? $lang : "en"; return include LANGUAGE_DIR."/$file.php";`

Comment: ... and use as this: `$translations = $lang->getLanguage($language);` and `$translations['commentNotSent']` to get the translation.